# Create a CSV file dump/feed whenever item of Content Type A is created

Tags: 7, feeds

I need to create a CSV dump/feed whenever a new item of "Content Type A" is created, with only that new item's info in the CSV. How can this be accomplished? For example, if 100 new items of "Content Type A" were created today, there would be 100 separate CSV files with the field values for each of those content items.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Views Data Export](https://drupal.org/project/views_data_export). It can create a CSV from Node content.

It sounds like you need this to somehow be recurring over time ... this is a tall order and so I wont be providing much code, but will outline a possible solution:

- Implement [hook_cron_queue_info()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_cron_queue_info/7). This is a cron task that runs off of a custom Queue. You can insert a `NID` every time a node is created into a custom queue you've created named `MyCSVQueue`. Every time a node is created it gets added to this queue -- when you process the queue you create individual csv files.
- Use either [hook_node_insert](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7) or [Rules](http://www.drupal.org/project/rules) to place the `NID` into the work queue.
- In your queue worker function you pass the `NID` to a custom view that uses a contextual filter to load the `NID`. Or, you may be able to use [node_export](https://drupal.org/project/node_export) to create the CSV data as well. You then simply use the Drupal File API and file_save() to store the csv file somewhere in your public/private drupal filesystem.

If the default Cron options of drupal dont suite your needs look at [Ultimate Cron](https://drupal.org/project/ultimate_cron)

**EDIT**

A slightly easier alternative:

Use:

- Use either [hook_node_insert](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7) or [Rules](http://www.drupal.org/project/rules) to run a snippet of custom PHP code. Simply create a file directory using the File API in public files as: `%files/csv_node_exports/MM-DD-YYYY`. Your snippet can create the directory if it doesnt exist today yet.
- then just export the node data to a CSV file. You may or may not have a `NID` yet ... you could always update the filename after the fact to reflect the actual `NID` assigned to the node.